# ModuleNotFoundError but path to module is correct

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project with my models, views, and URLs set up. The path structure is as follows:

```
--mainProject
--measurements
    --views.py
    --urls.py
    --models.py
    --migrations
    --templates.py
    --management
        --commands
            --add_data.py
            --clear_data.py
            --init.py
            --_pycache_
```

When building this project, I created the models.py first and then made migrations. Afterwards, I migrated. The add_data.py file adds data to the table and the clear_data.py file removes the data. I ran the add_data.py file and it worked once, but I had similar errors leading up. I forgot how I made it run through the command line. However, now if I delete the database and try to run the add_data.py file I get this error:

> from measurements.models import Area, Category, Location, Measurement
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'measurements'

Here's my code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Avg

class Area(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    latitude = models.FloatField()

    def number_of_locations(self):
        return len(self.location_set.all())

    # Function to get the average measurements of locations in area
    def average_measurement(self):
        return Measurement.objects.filter(location__area=self).aggregate(Avg('value'))['value__avg']

    # Get all category names for area
    def category_names(self):

            categories = self.category_set.all()
            cList = ""

            for category in categories:
                cList+= category.name + ", "

            return cList[:-2]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Location(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    altitude = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Altitude in feet")
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.area.name + ":" + self.name

class Measurement(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    value = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "measurement@" + self.location.__str__()


class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Area)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**add_data.py**

```
from measurements.models import Area, Category, Location, Measurement
import random
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.utils import timezone


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "adds sample entities to the application"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        area_data = [
            [1, "Grand Canyon", 20, 30],
            [2, "Boca Raton", 40, 50],
            [3, "Atlanta", 60, 70],
            [4, "Mount Hood", 80, 90],
            [5, "Mount Rainer", 46.5, 121.5],
            [6, "Saint Olaf", 44, 93],
            [7, "Mount St. Helens", 46, 122]
        ]

        for ad in area_data:
            a = Area(name=ad[1], id=ad[0], longitude=ad[2], latitude=ad[3])
            a.save()

        location_data = [
            [11, "South rim", 200, 1],
            [12, "North rim", 300, 1],
            [13, "Phantom Ranch", 100, 1],
            [14, "Waterfront", 10, 2],
            [15, "Town center", 15, 2],
            [16, "Town center", 310, 3],
            [17, "University", 320, 3],
            [18, "Mall", 330, 3],
            [19, "Airport", 350, 3],
            [20, "South pass", 3500, 4],
            [21, "North rim", 4500, 4],
            [22, "Crater", 4000, 4],
            [23, "North pass", 14000, 5],
            [24, "South glacier", 15000, 5],
            [25, "Ranger station", 16000, 5],
            [26, "Summit", 17000, 5],
            [27, "Yttrboe", 250, 6],
            [28, "Science", 250, 6],
        ]

        no_measurements_location_ids = [23]

        for locd in location_data:
            loc = Location(id=locd[0], name=locd[1], altitude=locd[2])
            a = Area.objects.get(pk=locd[3])
            loc.area = a
            loc.save()

        category_data = [
            [31, "Volcanos", "Areas that are on volcanoes", [4, 5]],
            [32, "East", "Areas that are in the east", [2, 3]],
            [33, "West", "Areas that are in the west", [1, 4, 5]],
            [34, "Wetlands", "Areas that are wetlands", []]
            ]

        for catd in category_data:
            cat = Category(id=catd[0], name=catd[1], description=catd[2])
            cat.save()
            for memb_id in catd[3]:
                a = Area.objects.get(pk=memb_id)
                cat.members.add(a)
            cat.save()

        num_meas_per_loc = 10

        for locd in location_data:
            loc_id = locd[0]
            if loc_id not in no_measurements_location_ids:
                loc = Location.objects.get(pk=loc_id)
                for meas_id in range(loc_id*100, loc_id*100+num_meas_per_loc):
                    val = random.uniform(5+loc_id*3, 15+loc_id*3)
                    meas = Measurement(value=val, id=meas_id, date=timezone.now())
                    meas.location = loc
                    meas.save()
```

What am I doing wrong that produces this error?

Comment: Is your project root folder and apps have starting with `M` caps ?

Comment: @RajaSimon No it doesn't

Comment: You haven't shown any `__init__.py` files (except for one incorrect `init.py`)

Comment: How are you trying to run the `add_data.py` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_data.py` is a management command, not a standalone script, so you should run it as:

```
python manage.py add_data
```

If you run `add_data.py` directly, then your main project directory (the one containing `manage.py`) won't be on the Python path automatically, so you'll get an import error.